# Chaining Filters Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

Basically I want to chain filters.

A search filter 
A checkbox styled price filter with pre-defined values e.g < 10$ ,$20 -$50, $50+ 
A checkbox styled filter for selecting 'topics'
A select styled sort filter 'ascending, descending, highest and lowest price'

I have made a search filter which works but I cannot get my head around making all the filters work together.

I will be grateful for any help I get. :)

Thanks in advance.

***JS***

```
    filteredSearch() {
      return this.products.filter(p => p.topic.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()));

    }
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="block" v-for="product in filteredSearch">
```

Comment: Just keep chaining `filter` methods. `this.products.filter([search filter]).filter([checkbox filter]) ...` Then implement a custom sort method that takes your sort filter into account.

Comment: Can you chain with computed properties? Or only methods?

Comment: Yuppers, a computed property is just a fancy term for a function. You can do whatever you want inside that function and just return the value. Ok maybe not _anything_, anything in a promise or async would break it but outside of that anything you want.

Comment: `filteredSearch: function() {
          return this.products
           .filter(function(product) {
          return product.topic.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })` I tried this, but it stopped working completely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is some confusion on how to do this so I will throw together a quick example as an answer so I can post a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks Adam, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments about chaining the filter calls here is an example of how you would do that.

```js
    filterSearch() {
       return this.products
                  .filter(product => product.topic.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()))
                  .filter(product => product.price < checkbox.Value)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Adam this works. I'm guessing `checkbox.Value` is bind by using v-model?

Comment: Well `checkbox.Value` is just a placeholder indicating that you would need to get the value of that checkbox there.

Answer (score 1):

as the comments say, multiple chained filters will work. Since your letting the user filter dynamically based on check boxes you could do something like:

```
computed: {
  filteredSearch() {
      return this.products.filter((p) => {
        if (this.ltTenFilterApplied) {
          return p.value < 10;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      })
      .filter(// filter based on btwnTwentyAndFiftyFilterApplied the same way )
      .fitler((filteredP) => {
        if (this.tagsToFilterBy && this.tagsToFilterBy.length > 0) {
          return this.tagsToFilterBy.includes(filteredP.categoryTagName);
        } esle {
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
},
data() {
  return {
    ltTenFilterApplied: false,
    btwnTwentyAndFiftyFilterApplied: false,
    topicsToFilterBy: [],
    products: [// things here],
  };
},
methods: {
  addTopicsFilter(aFilterFromClickEvent) {
    this.topicsToFilterBy.push(aFilterFromClickEvent);
  },
  removeTopicFilter(bFilterFromClickEvent) {
    this.topicsToFilterBy = this.topicsToFilterBy.filter(bFilterFroMClickEvent);
  }
}
```